# Assembly - Print Character

Tags: assembly, ascii, nasm, bios

I'm trying to learn assembly language and made some simple steps so far. I can display characters on the screen using their ascii-id, but now I want to store the ids of specific characters into a variable and print them. Unfortunately this does not work :) My code only displays a space on the screen. Thank you for each kind of help!

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

; MOV AL, 48 (works)

MOV AL, [false]
CALL PrintCharacter

JMP $

PrintCharacter:
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BH, 0x00
MOV BL, 0x07

INT 0x10
RET

false db 48
true db 49

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
DW 0xAA55
```

Comment: Assembly for which processor?

Comment: I don't know. I'm using a virtual machine, but my computer, on wich VMWare is running, has a AMD processor.

Comment: I'll try being more specific. When you say that you're trying to learn an Assembly language, the Assembly of which processor are you trying to learn?

Comment: I don't know. NASM? I followed this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php

Comment: The assembler used here is NASM (Netwide Assembler). **NASM is an 80x86 assembler** designed for portability and modularity

Comment: Thanks! Good to know what I'm really doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the pair `ds:false` to point to the address of `false`, so you need to setup a data segment (via the `ds` register). Because of your `[ORG 0x7c00]` directive, the value of the label `false` is already where it needs to be, so you can just set `ds` to 0.

```
xor ax,ax
mov ds,ax
```

Just put that at the beginning of your code.